# How to visualize a dependency graph (product roadmap) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this in Google Sheets:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|            Items             |                    depends on                     |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Get 2 slices of bread        |                                                   |
| Put peanut butter on 1 slice | Get 2 slices of bread                             |
| Put jelly on 1 slice         | Get 2 slices of bread                             |
| Put away peanut butter jar   | Put peanut butter on 1 slice                      |
| Put slices together          | Put peanut butter on 1 slice,Put jelly on 1 slice |
| Put away jelly jar           | Put jelly on 1 slice                              |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

and want to display a dependency graph synced with it in the same sheet, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I made the add-on.

Since Google Sheets do not support Dependency graph visualization. There is now [**an add-on for it**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dependency-graph-visualiz/bainjkfkhoipphfdlnlcnoddiggamjpd?utm_source=permalink).

[image]

Note: on the technical side, a URL is generated by the add-on and passed to [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com/) to render the graph as SVG, then the `IMAGE(url)` Google Sheet function is used to render it directly inside a cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you rather not install an add-on (because of the permissions you need to grant it) and the data in your spreadsheet doesn't change very often. You can use this solution that doesn't require an add-on. After a one-time setup (column C), you can recreate the graph manually in under a minute.

1. Next to column A and B, use these formula's in column C:

```
="  """&A2&""" -> """&B2&""""
="  """&A3&""" -> """&B3&""""
etc
```

2. Copy column C into the `digraph G { ... }` block on [webgraphviz.com](http://www.webgraphviz.com/)
3. Click Generate Graph!
4. Screen capture the graph part back to the spreadsheet

And you're done. Here's an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZ3mUzvR0_Bz3MOqbZCN_zLJMk7BBQoMnT7aUsN2vYg/edit?usp=sharing) with the formula's:

[image: result in webgraphviz.com]

### Limitation

This solution doesn't work when an item depends on multiple items using the comma notation. Need to fix that... I work around for now is to copy the offending line into multiple lines each with one of the dependency. I created a workaround sheet in the spreadsheet to demonstrate that. Than you get this:

```
digraph G {
  "Get 2 slices of bread" -> ""
  "Put peanut butter on 1 slice" -> "Get 2 slices of bread"
  "Put jelly on 1 slice" -> "Get 2 slices of bread"
  "Put away peanut butter jar" -> "Put peanut butter on 1 slice"
  "Put slices together" -> "Put peanut butter on 1 slice" /*first one*/
  "Put slices together" -> "Put jelly on 1 slice" /*second one*/
  "Put away jelly jar" -> "Put jelly on 1 slice"
}
```